# Implementation of Service Broker API for Cassandra and Aerospike in open source Cloud Foundry

Tags: cassandra, aerospike, cloud-foundry

I need to use Cassandra and Aerospike as services with open source cloud foundry. Service Broker implementations with PCF i.e. Pivotal Cloud Foundry, are available as tiles for most DBs. Can these be used with open source cloud foundry? If yes, how? If not, how to go about implementing the service broker API for my use case? Are there any already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aerospike is available on PCF - https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-now-available-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry-pcf-aerospike-blog-post-october-19-2016/3524

- the write up then refers to:

https://network.pivotal.io/products/aerospike

Comment: As I mentioned, I need service broker implementation for open source cloud foundry and not PCF. I have learnt that PCF tiles cannot be used with open source cf.